# Python coding issue for csv read

Tags: python, pycharm

Have a simple code where 
goal:

> 1. open a csv file as list print it --> worked
> 2. open a csv file as dictionary
>
>    print it --> working
>
>    modify it --> **is the code correct for it?**
>
>    **print again --> not working**

using Pycharm for debug and can't identify the issue. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
import sys
import csv

def print_csv_list(list_in):
    """
    function takes a list of lists and prints # of lines instructed by counter parameter
    :param list_in: list of lists
    :return: no return
    """
    counter = 0
    for line in list_in:
        if counter < 2:
            for item in line:
                sys.stdout.write(item.strip(",") + "\t")
                sys.stdout.flush()
            print("\n")
            counter +=1

def print_csv_file(file_dict):
    for dict_item in file_dict:
        print dict_item

def modify_dict(file_dict):
    print_csv_file(file_dict)
    for dict_item in file_dict:
        for k, v in dict_item.iteritems():
            if k == "ral_file":
                dict_item[k] = v.strip("_regs")
    print_csv_file(file_dict)

def parse_ral_file(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, 'r')as print_file:
        file_read = csv.reader(print_file, delimiter=',')
        print_csv_file(file_read)
    with open(csvfile, 'r')as dict_file:
        file_dict = csv.DictReader(dict_file, delimiter=',')
        modify_dict(file_dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = sys.argv[1]
    parse_ral_file(x)
```

Comment: Could you provide us with some traceback, what Errors were raised, any other debug information?

Answer (score 2):

When you iterate through a generator (including a file), you leave the pointer at the end. This means any subsequent iteration will result in empty content. You need to use `seek` and make the pointer go back to the start of the file.

```
with open(csvfile, 'r')as dict_file:
    modify_dict(dict_file)

def modify_dict(dict_file):
    file_dict = csv.DictReader(dict_file, delimiter=',')
    print_csv_file(file_dict)
    dict_file.seek(0) # If you remove this line, the second `print_csv_file` 
                      # won't print anything
    print_csv_file(file_dict)
```

Comment: Positioning the file back to zero causes the DictReader to include the header line in any subsequent iterations, I really didn't expect that.

Comment: thanks@cwallenpoole. is there a way to cast the file_dict into an empty dictionary and use it from there? example:  file_dict = csv.DictReader(dict_file, delimiter=',') empty_dict = dict(file_dict)

Comment: @DibyenduDey It seems like what you really want is to just cast it to a list `list_of_dicts = list(file_dict)`. Or, you could try out pandas.read_csv, but that will be a much higher learning curve.